# Convergence of Neumann-series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to proof the following:

If $\\$  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty$ $D^k$ with $D=diag(d_1, \ldots, d_n)$ and $|d_1|, \ldots, |d_n| < 1$ converges, the Neumann series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty$ $B^k$ to any similar matrix B also converges.

I know I can write $B=S^{-1}DS$, but how does this help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of Neumann series you stated, $B^k=(S^{-1}DS)^k=S^{-1}DS\ \cdot S^{-1}DS\ ...\ S^{-1}DS=S^{-1}D^kS$, Therefore $\sum_{k=0}^n B^k=\sum_{k=0}^n S^{-1}D^kS=S^{-1}(\sum_{k=0}^nD^k)S$.

Since you know that $\sum_{k=0}^nD^k$ converges already (actually the limit is $(I-D)^{-1}$), we know $\sum_{k=0}^n B^k=S^{-1}(\sum_{k=0}^nD^k)S$ also converges, and the limit is $S^{-1}(I-D)^{-1}S=(S^{-1}(I-D)S)^{-1}=(I-B)^{-1}$.

Let me know if this solves your question.

Comment: yes! thank you so much! that helped quite a lot!

Comment: good to know i can help. good luck!